# Akka-HTTP server HTTPS Support

Tags: java, https, akka, akka-http, sslcontext

I found myself struggling to enable https support for our akka-http java application.
The documentation page (https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/server-side/server-https-support.html) should be helping, but for some reason in my case it does not.

From what I got from that page - the idea is to obtain an `HttpsConnectionContext` instance and use it as a parameter for the `http.setDefaultClientHttpsContext(...)` method call before actually doing some route binding.

What I have so far:

Code that creates an `SSLContext` from the configuration:

```
public static SSLContext getSslContext(String path, ActorSystem system) {
    final AkkaSSLConfig sslConfig = AkkaSSLConfig.get(system);

    final Config overrides = system.settings().config().getConfig(path);
    final Config defaults = system.settings().config().getConfig("ssl-config");

    final SSLConfigSettings config = SSLConfigFactory.parse(overrides.withFallback(defaults));

    return new ConfigSSLContextBuilder(
        new AkkaLoggerFactory(system),
        config,
        sslConfig.buildKeyManagerFactory(config),
        sslConfig.buildTrustManagerFactory(config)
    ).build();
}
```

Actual peace of configuration:

```
akka.ssl-config {
  trustManager = {
    stores = [
      { type: "JKS" , path: "xxx-truststore.jks", password = "xxx"}
    ]
  }
  keyManager = {
    stores = [
      { type: "JKS" , path: "xxx-keystore.jks", password = "xxx"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Using them to enable https:

```
final SSLContext sslContext = Utils.getSslContext("akka.ssl-config", system);
final HttpsConnectionContext httpsContext = ConnectionContext.https(sslContext);
http.setDefaultClientHttpsContext(httpsContext);

final CompletionStage<ServerBinding> binding =
    http.bindAndHandle(routeFlow, ConnectHttp.toHost("localhost",443), materializer);
```

But that actually does nothing. If I try to make some https call to the server I get the following exception:

`Illegal request, responding with status '400 Bad Request': Unsupported HTTP method: The HTTP method started with 0x16 rather than any known HTTP method. Perhaps this was an HTTPS request sent to an HTTP endpoint?`

I'm probably missing something, but I have no idea what

Answer (score 0):

looks like my fault after all)
the method to use is obviously `http.setDefaultServerHttpContext(...)` not `http.setDefaultClientHttpsContext(...)`